# Get all the Links from Bing Search api and add them to array

Tags: java, xml, json, bing-api

I have a question, because I am new to Bing Search API and I am not familiar how to use it. I am trying to get all the links from the Bing search result. So I am searching for keyword. Is working but I want to get the links of the results that I got from the Bing Search API that I have included in my Java application. The problem is that I want to retrieve and save the links into an array. So I am using XML to parse it to JSON. But the main problem when i am trying to get the Urls or links I cannot get them. Does anyone has an idea how to do it or where I am doing it wrong?

I want for example to get http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omonoia (one of the search results of Bing search API)

Here is some of the code:

```
String str = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&sensor=true";
URL url = new URL(str);
InputStream is = url.openStream();
int ptr = 0;
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
while ((ptr = is.read()) != -1) {
builder.append((char) ptr);
}
String xml = builder.toString();

JSONObject jsonObject = XML.toJSONObject(xml);
System.out.println(jsonObject.toString());
System.out.println(jsonObject.get("id"));
```

some of the output:

```
"feed":{"entry":[{"id":"https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Data.ashx/Bing/Search/v1/Web?Query=' what      is omonoia'&$skip=0&$top=1","title":{"type":"text","content":"WebResult"},"updated":"2015-01-15T14:35:57Z","content":{"m:properties":{"d:Url":{"content":"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AC_Omonia","m:type":"Edm.String"},"d:DisplayUrl":{"content":"en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AC_Omonia","m:type":"Edm.String"},"d:Title":{"content":"AC Omonia - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia","m:type":"Edm.String"},"d:Description":{"content":"Athletic Club Omonoia Nicosia, commonly referred to as Omonoia, is a Cypriot professional football club based in the capital city, Nicosia. The club was established ...","m:type":"Edm.String"},"d:ID":{"content":"88cf85ab-f077-4f2b-8037-f3d3447b9d34","m:type":"Edm.Guid"}},"type":"application/xml"}},{"id":"https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Data.ashx/Bing/Search/v1/Web?Query=' what is omonoia'&$skip=1&$top=1","title":{"type":"text","content":"WebResult"},"updated":"2015-01-15T14:35:57Z","content":{"m:properties":{"d:Url":{"content":"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omonoia","m:type":"Edm.String"},"d:DisplayUrl":{"content":"en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omonoia","m:type":"Edm.String"},"d:Title":{"content":"Omonoia - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia","m:type":"Edm.String"},"d:Description":{"content":"Omonoia may refer to: Omonoia Square, one of Athens' main squares, Omonoia Station, the subway station located on the square or Omonoia, the neighborhood around it.","m:type":"Edm.String"},"d:ID":{"content":"4668962f-c8cb-43b1-a12d-19d8aee944bb","m:type":"Edm.Guid"}},"type":"application/xml"}},{"id":"https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Data.ashx/Bing/Search/v1/Web?Query=' what is omonoia'&$skip=2&$top=1","title":{"type":"text","content":"WebResult"},"updated":"2015-01-15T14:35:57Z","content":{"m:properties":{"d:Url":{"content":"http://wikitravel.org/en/Athens/Omonia","m:type":"Edm.String"},"d:DisplayUrl":{"content":"wikitravel.org/en/Athens/Omonia","m:type":"Edm.String"},"d:Title":{"content":"Athens/Omonia - Wikitravel - The Free Travel Guide","m:type":"Edm.String"},"d:Description":{"content":"Omonia Square is the center of Athens, and is composed of the actual square together with the surrounding streets, open areas and assemblage of grand buildings that ...","m:type":"Edm.String"},"d:ID":{"content":"b711b509-d478-48c4-ad44-51e9d87a5646","m:type":"Edm.Guid"}},"type":"application/xml"}},{"id":"https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Data.ashx/Bing/Search/v1/Web?Query=' what is omonoia'&$skip=3&$top=1","title":{"type":"text","content":"WebResult"},"updated":"2015-01-15T14:35:57Z","content":{"m:properties":{"d:Url":{"content":"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nZfkY7b5vIo","m:type":"Edm.String"},"d:DisplayUrl":{"content":"www.youtube.com/watch?v=nZfkY7b5vIo","m:type":"Edm.String"},"d:Title":{"content":"OMONOIA Vs ANORTHOSI 3-2 - YouTube","m:type":"Edm.String"},"d:Description":{"content":"OMONOIA Vs ANORTHOSI 3-2 - YouTube ... YouTube home","m:type":"Edm.String"},"d:ID":{"content":"a8870310-3a66-493e-9155-3608501305d2","m:type":"Edm.Guid"}},"type":"application/xml"}},{"id":"https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Data.ashx/Bing/Search/v1/Web?Query=' what is omonoia'&$skip=4&$top=1","title":{"type":"text","content":"WebResult"},"updated":"2015-01-15T14:35:57Z","content":{"m:properties":{"d:Url":{"content":"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EOg6rMweu38","m:type":"Edm.String"},"d:DisplayUrl":{"content":"www.youtube.com/watch?v=EOg6rMweu38","m:type":"Edm.String"},"d:Title":{"content":"OMONOIA Vs APOLLON 2-4 - YouTube","m:type":"Edm.String"},"
```

Some source code I got them from this question: [Parsing external XML to JSON in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3812091/parsing-external-xml-to-json-in-java)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can specify the format, so it is not necessary get in XML then parse to JSON. To get JSON just inform `$format` option in URL, like this:

```
https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/SearchWeb/Web?Query='what      is omonoia'&$format=json
```

Below an example that retrieves the urls:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.Base64;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class BingSearchApiSample {

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
        final String accountKey = "<Your Bing API Key>";
        final String bingUrlPattern = "https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search/Web?Query=%%27%s%%27&$format=JSON";

        final String query = URLEncoder.encode("'what      is omonoia'", Charset.defaultCharset().name());
        final String bingUrl = String.format(bingUrlPattern, query);

        final String accountKeyEnc = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString((accountKey + ":" + accountKey).getBytes());

        final URL url = new URL(bingUrl);
        final URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + accountKeyEnc);

        try (final BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()))) {
            String inputLine;
            final StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(inputLine);
            }
            final JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response.toString());
            final JSONObject d = json.getJSONObject("d");
            final JSONArray results = d.getJSONArray("results");
            final int resultsLength = results.length();
            for (int i = 0; i < resultsLength; i++) {
                final JSONObject aResult = results.getJSONObject(i);
                System.out.println(aResult.get("Url"));
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**EDIT**: JSON content look like in this link: http://pastebin.com/TcGg6SzN

**EDIT**: The sample generated the output below:

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AC_Omonia
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omonoia
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XDTjbljYoM8
http://wikitravel.org/en/Athens/Omonia
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JwwuQgg3O8o
http://www.omonoia.com.cy/
https://www.omonoia.com.cy/
http://www.athensguide.com/omonia.html
http://wn.com/This_Is_Omonoia
http://www.greece-athens.com/metro/omonoia.php
http://www.encyclo.co.uk/meaning-of-Omonoia
http://www.flickr.com/photos/mascarpone/sets/72157611666181729/
http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pra%C3%A7a_Omonia
http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omonoia,_Athens
http://omonoia.info/
http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=omonoia
http://www.omonia.org/omonoia/Fair_Play.shtml
https://www.linkedin.com/pub/omonoia-omonoia/11/8b2/695
http://www.ustream.tv/channel/ael---omonoia
http://www.omonia.org/about.shtml
http://www.cyclopaedia.info/wiki/Omonoia
http://www.thisisathens.org/taxonomy/term/15
http://allochiria.bandcamp.com/album/omonoia
http://www.dvbs.eu.org/omonoia/
http://www.facebook.com/pages/omonoia/307148722634077
http://omonoianews.com/
http://www.eurobasket.com/team.asp?Cntry=CYP&Team=1019
http://worddomination.com/omonoia.html
http://www.mixcloud.com/antreas-omonoia/
http://www.newhois.net/www/omonoia.com.cy.html
http://omonoiany.com/html/crete.html
http://vigorito.com.br/codigos/omonoia-fc
http://www.facebook.com/pages/OMONOIA/118545104824439
http://www.cyclopaedia.info/wiki/Omonoia-1
http://www.vipfilefinder.com/download/omonoia/
http://new.livestream.com/accounts/380859
http://www.sevodnya.com/omonoia/
http://www.answers.com/Q/When_was_Omonoia_-_organization_-_created
http://omonoia.com.cubestat.com/
https://twitter.com/eurovison
http://omonoialinks.com/?source=7&date=yes
http://members.tripod.com/antonis_antoniou/season9900/omoapoeE.html
http://www.quickiwiki.com/en/Omonoia,_Athens
https://www.torrentz.com/search?q=omonoia
http://www.omonoia.org/
http://omonoia.com.cy.onlinenoffline.com/
http://omonoia.com.cy.hypestat.com/
http://wn.com/Omonoia__This_Is_My_Life
http://new.livestream.com/accounts/8561914
http://omonoia-nafpaktou.gr.ipaddress.com/
```

Comment: I tried to do it but I get this error: org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["d"] not found.
 at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:454)
 at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONObject(JSONObject.java:553)....

Comment: @user4457996 which the content of the response? You replace <Your Bing API Key>?

Comment: Yes i replaced it. but i think the command that need to take the url or any tag is wrong..

Comment: @user4457996 edited the example with result. Try to see content of `response`.

Comment: which library need to download forBase64.getEncoder()?

Comment: @user4457996 is from Java 8 SDK. What are you using? You can use BASE64Encoder from `sun.misc` or `Base64` from apache commons-codec.

Comment: yes i fix it, but now when i run it i get the following error java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search/Web?Query=%27%27what+is+omonoia%27%27&$format=JSON ...
 at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1625)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)

Comment: @user4457996 401 is HTTP code for `Unauthorized`. Check your app key.

Comment: @Bruno César: thanks for the code. But, I get only 50 results. What if I want all the URL results??

Comment: @user2192774 you did it? If not, you just need to get `__next` property of json and make another call.

Comment: Note that the URL was changed, so you need to change ../Search/Web... to .../SearchWeb/v1/Web...